# rubymotion, game centre and creating a multiplayer game

Tags: ios, center, rubymotion

Does anyone know of any good resources/tutorials/sample code for creating multiplayer functionality within a rubymotion iOS game?

I am currently using Joybox and I want to integrate iOS Game Center to enable two players to play the same game at once.

I have found a great tutorial by Ray Wenderlich:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12

But it's Xcode and Objective-C centric, and I'm having a hard time translating it to RM, so any other source of information would potentially be a big help. Any advice is very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a part in particular that is causing issues?

Comment: I guess it's a total lack of Xcode experience which is holding me back. For instance, in Ray's tutorial there will be instructions to edit certain header files in Xcode. I have no idea how to implement that kind of step in rubymotion (as there are no header files in rm). Making a multiplayer game in RM seem like a non-starter for me. I've only been programming for 6 months so I can only translate basic methods from obj-c to RM right now. It seems like I should bite the bullet and learn how to handle Xcode, for lack of a beginner friendly/ easier alternative.

Comment: Most of the time you won't need to worry about the header files at all. RubyMotion is great because you don't need to deal with xCode and can just use whichever text editor you're happy with. Have you converted that game they're using to RubyMotion?

Comment: I've been following the steps in the tutorial but making my own game, instead of making the tutorial game. I might give it another shot today and try and make a game multiplayer in RM. The game center and the multiplayer aspect is the main thing I'm having problems implementing. Thanks of the reply.

Comment: After 2 days of playing with Xcode I've decided to stick with the Rubymotion cause. Xcode drains all my enthusiasm completely. Any GC with RM tutorials are welcome.